# How to transfer tokbox archive videos into my own server

Tags: tokbox

i am very new to tokbox and interested to know whether i can download and store the archived videos/data from tokbox into my own server through rest api without using microsoft azure or amazon s3.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here. You can provide your own S3/azure bucket, or you can use the default OpenTok bucket, where you will have your archives available for downloading for 72 hours. If you don't want to use your own bucket, just let OpenTok store it, and, when you have finished the archiving session, use the API to get the s3 url to download it wherever you want.
If you want the archive to be created in your own server, the answer is simple. You cannot.
I hope this helps.