# Tokbox: Can I use my own storage to upload archive videos, if possible how?

Tags: javascript, azure, amazon-s3, tokbox

I am currently using Tokbox for remote conference and now have a trouble in storing archive videos, at least for 6 months.

I have already read tokbox developer guide and many articles and I found that I have to use Amazon S3 bucket or Azure container to upload completed archive videos.

```
// connect to session
  var self = this;
  var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
  self.session = session;

  // Subscribe to a newly created stream
  session.on("streamCreated", function(event) {
    session.subscribe(...
    )
  });

  var publisher = OT.initPublisher(...
  );

  session.connect(
    token,
    ...
  );
```

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/
[How to transfer tokbox archive videos into my own server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180609/how-to-transfer-tokbox-archive-videos-into-my-own-server)
...

I want to confirm the possibility of using my own storage to upload archives and if not whether using Amazon S3 bucket or Azure container is perfect and secure for secret information.

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox developer here.

You can use your own Amazon S3 bucket or Microsoft Azure container. Is that what you mean by "my own storage"?

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
I mean the server storage where my web application running.
And the following is the answer I received from tokbox team.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you that we do not provide any way to configure servers other than Amazon and Azure. The completed archive files will either upload to any of these (whichever you have configured) or archives are available for retrieval by download from the OpenTok cloud through your Account dashboard https://tokbox.com/account/.
Archives made available on the OpenTok cloud are available for 72 hours from the time they are created. Read more about archiving here: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/

Comment: In your case, you would have to do it manually or write a script that would download the files from the location where they are available and then upload it to your server.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem why you can't just use your own Amazon S3 account to store TokBox recordings?